# a column , which was originally of object type, has been converted to int type

Tags: types

When I output the entire dataframe, the displayed data is normal, including UUID formatted strings

[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p36jd.png)

But when I only output the 'base_file' column, the data is incorrect. The data type has been changed to int64 and the values have become 0.

[pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wl9B2.png)

I'm not sure how this scenario occurred, but it may have been after I used 'df.drop' to delete data. Also, this is not a consistent issue, as it only occurs sometimes.

```
df.drop(df[(df['base_file'] == "851b5fa5-6ad9-4a5a-9d66-26d71f3a9c6d")].index.tolist(), axis=0, inplace=True)
```

how to solve the problem

Comment: I found that this is related to an internal caching error in the dataframe. When I access the data using df['base_file'], I am actually accessing the internal cache. Additionally, I found that I can get the correct data using df.to_csv(), but I get incorrect data using df.to_dict().